# UI5 VizFrame info/dual_line, plotArea window end does not work with date object

Tags: sapui5

i am trying to get a plot (vizType: info/dual_line) that initially stops at a given Date (zoom should still work). Available data provides much more data points but the first view should be from 'Today' to '7 Days ago'.

This is my very first question here...please excuse if there is anything important missing.

Feed:

```js
new FeedItem({
 uid: "categoryAxis",
 type: "Dimension",
 values: ["CreationTimestamp"]
})
```

Dataset:

```js
dimensions: [
 name: CreationTimestamp,
 value: "{CreationTimestamp}",
 dataType: "date"
]
```

Properties:

```js
plotArea: {
 window: {
   end: {
     categoryAxis: {
       CreationTimestamp: new Date(1673442669000)
     }
   }
 }
}
```

Data:

```js
[
 {
   CreationTimestamp: date-object,
   A: 12,
   B: ...,
   ...
 },
 ...
]
```

I also tried to use the millis of the Date instead of the date-object in data and vizProperties. it produces the same result.
The Visualization looks correct in both cases (Date-Object and Millis) but the plot end does never match the one from properties.
I implemented it that way that the value for plotArea.window.end.categoryAxis.CreationTimestamp matches exactly one of the values in data (same result as before - the plot is drawn till the last data point).

Is there any obvious problem with my implementation or am i expecting the wrong result?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After debugging sap-viz-info-charts.js i found out that i simply have to set the date.getTime() value to plotArea.window.end.categoryAxis. basically like so:

```js
plotArea: {
 window: {
   end: {
     categoryAxis: {
       CreationTimestamp: 1673442669000
     }
   }
 }
}
```

after this change i still can zoom in and out and the vizFrame plot initially ends at the correct timestamp.